# Is survey type questions allowed in the main site?

Tags: discussion

Is it allowed to ask a question in our main site regarding all the (best) techniques available currently?

Suppose there is a text which has to be converted in to a sequence of numbers, then can I ask questions **What are the best available techniques for the converting text to a sequence of numbers** in the main site?

Answer (score 3):

This type of question could lead to long lists or opinions, so I would suggest that when asking these questions people should ask for **examples** of X, something like

> Currently, what are **some examples** of the most used techniques to solve problem Z? As a reference, can you also provide a link to the research paper that introduced them?

Alternatively, if you're looking for comprehensive surveys, you can explicitly say that you're looking for papers or books that do those surveys, so you could say that you would appreciate that people link to those surveys.

So, when asking that type of question, the keys are

1. to restrict the question in some way, so that it doesn't require long answers, which, in general, aren't really suitable for our site. Always keep in mind that your question should not have multiple answers that are inconsistent with each other (although there are exceptions to this, such as when a problem can be solved in different ways). This would occur if you ask a question that is not specific enough, but it would not occur if you ask for **examples** of models/techniques that can be used to solve some problem (provided that you clarify exactly what you're looking for).
2. avoid terms that will lead to opinions (such as "in your opinion...?" or "what do you think...?", so you should avoid questions like "**in your opinion**, what are the best models to solve this problem?")

Not a long time ago, we had two questions along these lines, which are ok for our site, as far as I'm concerned:

- [What are the most common deep reinforcement learning algorithms and models apart from DQN?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/20160/2444)
- [Is there a taxonomy of adversarial attacks?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/25064/2444)